# Identify products that have purchased more than 1 time

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to identify products that have purchased more than 1 time.

ERD diagram looks like this:

[image: ERD]

I wrote this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT good_name 
           FROM Goods
           JOIN Payments 
             on Payments.good = Goods.good_id
          WHERE good in (SELECT good 
                           FROM (SELECT good
                                      , COUNT(good) as c 
                                   FROM Payments 
                                  GROUP 
                                     BY good) as a 
                          WHERE c > 1)
```

It works, but is this code great?

Comment: select g.good_name as good_name, count(*) as purchased_count from Goods g left join Payments p on p.good = g.good_id group by 1 having purchased_count > 1;

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

Grouping would work better:

```
SELECT good_name 
FROM Goods 
JOIN Payments on Payments.good = Goods.good_id 
GROUP BY Goods.good_id 
HAVING COUNT(Payments.good) > 1
```

Probably you also need an index over `Payments.good` column.

It is also better to create another column in the table `Goods` which will hold success payments count and update it after each payment.

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY will make your query invalid.

Comment: As for MySQL 5.7.5 and higher thats not true. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html